# Moving flickering graphic on Ubuntu desktop

Tags: nvidia, graphics, xorg

I have a graphics issue in Ubuntu.

There is a pattern of random short lines that flicker and move slowly across the screen. I have a dual monitor setup and the pattern first occurs on the top left of the second monitor, then slowly moves right and wraps over such that it continues on the first monitor, shifted down by a few pixels.

I have a Nvidia GTX 580, running with the proprietary NVIDIA drivers. I would not exclude the possibility that there may be some hardware failure, as my card has been dropping some white powder, which apparently may be a sign that some capacitors are going to fail soon.

I would like to know whether this is a known phenomenon/bug though and if there's any possibility to fix this. However, I will test more carefully with a second video card.

Here is a screenshot of the pattern: the whole pattern flickers, with the two lines at the right also changing color from black to white.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem long ago and it turned out to be a hardware failure. Removing the proprietary drivers helped because the standard vga seemed to be easier on the card.

Still, I do not know enough about display technology to rule out other possibilities in your case.